# Set focus on input using javascript or css on text input that is hidden until user selects an option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am editing an existing form with inputs that are hidden until the user clicks on an option, and then text input will appear. I need to get that specific text input to have active focus once that happens. I would love to do this with CSS because I am not great with javascript, but here is a portion of that code:

```js
if ($("#frmSubmittedValue").val() == '') {
  return false;
}

if ($("#frmSubmittedValue").val() == 'Individual')
  $("#personSubmittedByValue").val('');
  
if ($("#frmProjectSub").val() == 0) {
  return false;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't set focus on an element in CSS. However you can use jQuery's [`.focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Who's afraid of some javascript? I've thrown in a little extra method `select()`

```js
function show_it() {
  document.querySelector("#f16").style.display = "block";
}

function focus_it() {
  document.querySelector("#f16").focus();
}

function select_it() {
  document.querySelector("#f16").select();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show_it(); focus_it(); select_it();">click</button>
<input id="f16" type="text" value="untitled" style="display:none">
```

Comment: Ha! Absolutely hate javascript and never properly learned how to use it, just how to finagle it so I can get it to do what I need at the time! ;) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can set focus with jQuery using the code below:

```js
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).focus();
});
```

There's a simple form example on the jQuery [site here](https://%20https://api.jquery.com/focus/).

As for making the element visible, start off having the element you don't want shown to be `display: none` and has `aria-hidden="true"` (so screen-readers avoid) and a `tabIndex="-1"` (so the user can't tab to it). Then, using an if condition, set the properties to `display: block`, `aria-hidden="false"` and `tabIndex="0"`.

I've put together a rough form with a few different input types. It's not perfect, but should give the general idea.

```js
function makeMeVisible(id) {
  $(id).parent().removeClass('hidden').attr('aria-hidden', 'false').attr('tabIndex', '0');
}

function makeMeVanish(id) {
  $(id).parent().addClass('hidden').attr('aria-hidden', 'true').attr('tabIndex', '-1')
}

/* Select the first input and listen out for when it gets clicked */
$('#itemOne').on('click', function() {
  /* If we are checked, run the  makeMeVisible function and set focus to the next element we want shown */
  if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
    makeMeVisible('#itemTwo');
    $('#itemTwo').focus();
  } else {
  /* If we're not, make the item vanish and set the focus back to the original element */
    makeMeVanish('#itemTwo');
    $('#itemOne').focus();
  }
})

/* Select elements need to listen for a change. When changes, get the selected option */
$('#itemTwo').on('change', function() {

/* Change what we do next based on what is chosen (looking at the value property) */
    switch($('#itemTwo option:selected').val()) {
    case "Value 1" :
      makeMeVanish('#itemFive');
      makeMeVisible('#itemFour');
      $('#itemFour').focus();
      break;
    case "Value 2" : 
      makeMeVanish('#itemFour');
      makeMeVisible('#itemFive');
      $('#itemFive').focus();
      break;
    default:
      /* If nothing is chosen, hide both */
      makeMeVanish('#itemFour');
      makeMeVanish('#itemFive');
      
  }
})
```

```css
.form-item + .form-item {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.form-item {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-item"><label><input type="checkbox" id="itemOne">Item one</label></div>
  <div class="form-item hidden" aria-hidden="true" tabIndex="-1">
    <label for="itemTwo">Item two</label>
    <select name="option" id="itemTwo">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value="Value 1">Option one</option>
      <option value="Value 2">Option two</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item hidden" aria-hidden="true" tabIndex="-1">
    <label for="itemThree">Item three</label>
    <input type="text" id="itemThree">
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-item hidden" aria-hidden="true" tabIndex="-1">
    <label for="itemFour">Item four (Option one)</label>
    <input type="text" id="itemFour">
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-item hidden" aria-hidden="true" tabIndex="-1">
    <label for="itemFive">Item five (Option two)</label>
    <input type="text" id="itemFive">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Wow this was so helpful! Thank you! I am going to implement this code now and see how it goes! :)

Comment: When i uncheck 'Item one', the 'Item two' goes invisible. But 'Item four' stays visible where it should only be visible when 'Item two' dropdown get selected with 'Option one' or 'Option two'.

Comment: @g78, It was only a rough example to demonstrate how this could be approached. I'll make some adjustments to my answer later today to fix that issue.